# $f(x)$ is an increasing function. $\langle X_1 \rangle > \langle X_2 \rangle \Rightarrow \langle f(X_1) \rangle > \langle f(X_2) \rangle$?

Tags: expected-value

Let $f(x)$ be an increasing function. Consider two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, with different probability distributions, such that $\langle X_1 \rangle > \langle X_2 \rangle$. Does it follow that $\langle f(X_1) \rangle > \langle f(X_2) \rangle$?

I think it does not. But I need a counterexample to be sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ be a discrete probability space with $\Pr(\omega_1)=\Pr(\omega_2)=1/2$.  Define

$$X_1(\omega_1)=0,\ X_1(\omega_2)=10$$

and

$$X_2(\omega_1)=2,\ X_2(\omega_2)=6$$

so that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_1) = \frac{0+10}{2} = 5 \gt 4 = \frac{2+6}{2} = \mathbb{E}(X_2)$$

as required.

Let $f:\{0,2,6,10\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function

$$f(0)=0,\ f(2)=7,\ f(6)=9,\ f(10)=10.$$

Obviously $f$ is (strictly) increasing.  But

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X_1)) = \frac{f(0)+f(10)}{2} = \frac{0+10}{2} = 5 \lt 8 = \frac{7+9}{2} = \frac{f(2)+f(6)}{2} = \mathbb{E}(f(X_2)).$$